# How to optimize images for ocr

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

Im working on a program to take Magic: The Gathering cards and read their names. So far I've gotten to cropping the title and having a pretty good processed image for tesseract to read the title.
[image: Here is what that image looks like:]

However, when I run
`print(pytesseract.image_to_string(new_imgT))`, where new_imgT is the image above. Instead of returning "Command Beacon", or anything close, it returns ♀. IS this a problem with the ocr, or my code? Thank you!
Edit:
Here is the full function responsible for reading the image from its directory and bringing it to this state

```
def readCard(path):
    imgG = cv2.imread(path, 0)     # 0 means grayscale
    imgT = cv2.resize( imgG, (745, 1040))[55:100, 55:680]
    new_imgT = (imgT >= 165)*255          # 230 is the threshold, change as desired
    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\tpixe\Documents\PYTESSERACT test\mask.png",new_imgT)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_imgT)
    print(text)
```

Edit 2:
I think the issue might be corruption or a datatype change of some sort. Calling cv2.imshow on new_imgT gives the error

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:/Users/runneradmin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-req-build-sn_xpupm/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:155: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'
```

Which from what I have seen through google searches means its in an improper format, or corrupted. However, the image will save as a png just fine. How do I fix something like this?

Comment: Hi, have you tried it on other images as well? Does the result change?

Comment: @BedirYilmaz I tested my tesseract using this image: http://jeroen.github.io/images/testocr.png
. It works just fine, weirdly enough still having a ♀ at the end of the string on a new line. Besides that it reads it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your `new_imgT`? It works fine for me if I load your image beforehand using `opencv`:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('nBmJO.png')
string_raw = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(string_raw)
# Command Beacon
```

Comment: be *very* careful with resampling an image while *not* maintaining **aspect ratio**. `img.resize` is not an OpenCV API either (nor numpy!).

Comment: My image raw is the exact same as above. The only difference being in the fact that instead of calling imread on this image, I start with the full card image, grayscale, crop, and threshold it. Then imread that. 
My code:  
`def readCard(path):
    imgG = cv2.imread(path, 0)     # 0 means grayscale  
    imgT = cv2.resize( imgG, (745, 1040))[55:100, 55:680] 
    new_imgT = (imgT >= 165)*255          # 230 is the threshold, change as desired
    cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\tpixe\Documents\PYTESSERACT test\mask.png",new_imgT)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(new_imgT)
    print(text)
`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You're right. I mixed things up and deleted this note.

Comment: @PixelmonMaster There seems to be a problem with dtypes. Try `new_imgT = (img >= 165)*np.uint8(255)` to force the ndarray to `uint8`

Comment: @Durtal That fixed it. It runs perfectly now, thanks!